# Can't store images to the database using Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I'm trying to create a very simple program which upload image to the database using Paperclip in ROR. But the image can't go to the database everytime I press SUBMIT. Can anyone please point me where I did wrong.

This is my LOG File

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-03-22 21:03:03 +1000
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"P1JjsD8GMBJbrAnOnc/RtTDDuVOCiv/z
sMhvM0Lzb3+bELWElYYN3FAVgERADmv8E1+dXK5nDais+LmmwaCa4Q==", "user"=>{"title"=>"eeee"
, "avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xa40e398 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:/
Users/GaryVLC/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20170322-15228-psq6nh.jpg>, @original
_filename="14563434_519556131584166_3038665901337502288_n.jpg", @content_type="imag
e/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[avatar]\"; filename=
\"14563434_519556131584166_3038665901337502288_n.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\
r\n">}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
Command :: file -b --mime "C:/Users/GaryVLC/AppData/Local/Temp/4233aadfd0ba434db17d
ee20d9613cee20170322-15228-tizi43.jpg"
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename 14563434_519556131584166_30386659013375022
88_n.jpg (image/jpeg from Headers, ["image/jpeg"] from Extension), content type dis
covered from file command: . See documentation to allow this combination.
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
Command :: file -b --mime "C:/Users/GaryVLC/AppData/Local/Temp/4233aadfd0ba434db17d
ee20d9613cee20170322-15228-qcbjc3.jpg"
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename 14563434_519556131584166_30386659013375022
88_n.jpg (image/jpeg from Headers, ["image/jpeg"] from Extension), content type dis
covered from file command: . See documentation to allow this combination.
Command :: file -b --mime "C:/Users/GaryVLC/AppData/Local/Temp/4233aadfd0ba434db17d
ee20d9613cee20170322-15228-1l2s8em.jpg"
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename 14563434_519556131584166_30386659013375022
88_n.jpg (image/jpeg from Headers, ["image/jpeg"] from Extension), content type dis
covered from file command: . See documentation to allow this combination.
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendering users/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 108ms (Views: 53.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Can I see User Model?

Comment: What is version of your paperclip gem?

Comment: I just solved that problem. I just realised my mistake by setting the path wrongly in the development.rb (Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin'). Now it's all good. Btw thank you for your respond!

Comment: Glad to know, that your issue resolved

Comment: I'm using version 5.1.0